# How can I remove a NPC (Minecraft Entity Player) from Tablist?

Tags: java, minecraft, bukkit

How can I remove a NPC from Tablist.

So far I have this:

```
public static void addNPCPacket(EntityPlayer npc) {
    for(Player player : Bukkit.getOnlinePlayers()) {
        PlayerConnection connection = ((CraftPlayer)player).getHandle().playerConnection;
        connection.sendPacket(new PacketPlayOutPlayerInfo(PacketPlayOutPlayerInfo.EnumPlayerInfoAction.ADD_PLAYER, npc));
        connection.sendPacket(new PacketPlayOutNamedEntitySpawn(npc));
        connection.sendPacket(new PacketPlayOutEntityHeadRotation(npc, (byte) (npc.yaw * 256 / 360)));
        Bukkit.getScheduler().runTaskLater(Main.getPlugin(), new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                connection.sendPacket(new PacketPlayOutPlayerInfo(PacketPlayOutPlayerInfo.EnumPlayerInfoAction.REMOVE_PLAYER, npc));
            }
        }, 10);


    }
}
```

In this case, the NPC is not in the tablist, but has no skin either.
But if I remove the REMOVE_PLAYER event, the NPC has a skin but is in the tablist.

Comment: What is your server version ?

Comment: For me, your code works with server in online mode and with the `textures` property from my own profile

Comment: So, it's fine ?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by code below:

```java
npc.setPlayerListName(""); // hide npc name in tab
```